# What are pinctrl states and handles in relation to the device tree?

Tags: device-tree

I have a node with the following

```
        mmc0: mmc@11230000 {
            compatible = "mediatek,mt8186-mmc", "mediatek,mt8183-mmc";
            pinctrl-names = "default", "state_uhs", "state_eint";
            pinctrl-0 = <&mmc0_default>;
            pinctrl-1 = <&mmc0_state_uhs>;
            pinctrl-2 = <&mmc0_state_eint>;
            ...
        };

        &pio {
            mmc0_default: mmc0-0 {
                ...

                pins_cmd_dat {
                    pinmux = <...>;
                    bias-pull-up = <MTK_PUPD_SET_R1R0_01>;
                    input-enable;
                    drive-strength = <MTK_DRIVE_4mA>;
                };
                ...
            };
        };
```

When probing the device I get

```
[    0.227736] mtk-msdc 11230000.mmc: no init pinctrl state
[    0.227882] mtk-msdc 11230000.mmc: no sleep pinctrl state
[    0.227904] mtk-msdc 11230000.mmc: no idle pinctrl state
[    0.228444] mtk-msdc 11230000.mmc: Linked as a consumer to regulator.31
[    0.228763] mtk-msdc 11230000.mmc: Linked as a consumer to regulator.14
[    0.228822] mtk-msdc 11230000.mmc: Failed getting OCR mask: -22
```

My assumption is that in my code above,`pinctrl-names = "default"` is the state, and `pinctrl-0 = <&mmc0_default>;` points to the pincontrol that handles the state.
It seems it can be set from a driver in c code from [here](https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/master/include/linux/pinctrl/pinctrl-state.h) but can it be set as a property in the device tree?
Is there a way to set in the device tree?

Comment: Have you read the kernel docs on the [`pinctrl` subsystem](https://www.kernel.org/doc/html/v4.15/driver-api/pinctl.html)?